# Javascript Taxi fare

Tags: javascript

I got the function setup and variables taken care. I am trying to **calculate taxi fare per start zone**, **end zone** and **elapsed time**.

Here what I have so far but it is not calculating well.

It keeps giving me `$5`

```
if( startZone == 1 && endZone == 1 ){ 
    totalTaxiFare = baseCharge;

    if( timeCovered > 0 && timeCovered <= 4 ){  
        baseCharge = 5.00;
        charge = (0.75/timeCovered)*timeCovered; 
        totalTaxiFare = baseCharge + charge; 
    }
}

if( startZone == 1 && endZone == 2 ){           
    totalTaxiFare = baseCharge;         
    if( timeCovered > 4 && timeCovered <= 10 ){
        baseCharge = 7.00;          
        charge =( 3.00 + (0.50 * ( timeCovered - 4 ) * ( 0.75 / timeCovered ) * timeCovered ) );
        totalTaxiFare = baseCharge + charge;        
    }
}

document.writeln("<p> The total taxi fare is $" + totalTaxiFare + "</p>");
```

Comment: If the time>0<4, charge is 0.75 per minute

Comment: If the taxi starts at point >0 but <4 the charge is 0.75 per minute with a base charge of $5

Comment: If think it should rather give you `5.75`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if I got the math correctly since I had to guess what the rates were by looking at the pattern. There's that zone thing I'm not sure what that's about, but by looking in the original code, I think it's a conditional to change the calculations for working 2 shifts?

Anyways, you should always use `var` for your variables, otherwise all of that data is floating around in globalspace. You had this expression: `totalTaxiFare = baseCharge;` floating around being exposed. So it looks as if ultimately your `totalTaxiFare` was constantly being changed to `baseCharge` which is at a constant value of 5.00. If you used `var` and kept the majority of your variables local, you'd probably get different results, but with the expressions you had those results wouldn't be accurate.

I'm definitely not a math wizard (lazy in high school), but is this an expression that would yield an appropriate result for cab fare?: `

```
(0.75/timeCovered)*timeCovered;
```

Ok, parenthesis first and we'll say 3 minutes? 3 hours? 3 time units I guess.

`(.75/3)*3` which is `(.25)*3` which is `.75` so that was changed into a more appropriate expression:

```
(.75)*timeCovered;
```

So that would be

`(.75)*3 = 2.25`

Sorry if I sound harsh, I think that if you want to program, you should pay special attention to your math. Even if your syntax is flawless, it won't help if the math is even a little off.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzMEGFm2bXxFP68G1HxK?p=preview), like I said before, I guessed as to how the expressions are done because you didn't provide the complete rates or given any details on time. It looks like it's working like it should give it a try. Good luck, sir ;-)

Comment: Thanks Zer00ne, the hints and demo were very helpful. Got it square away. You are appreciated. Thanks,